# Exiting the App when Using FireBase Database on Android Studio (Java)

Tags: java, android, database, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Need to use firebase database I:

- Create an account on FireBase and create simple json file which shows the Hierarchy of the Database and Add it to the Realtime DataBase.
- Add these dependencies to the build.gradle(Module) File:

  compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:10.2.0'

  compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:10.2.0'
- I made two activities the main activity has two buttons when you click at the Sign in Button the second activity starts.(It was working very well until I add the Firebase using these commands):(the App Crush (Exiting))

  FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();

  DatabaseReference table_user = database.getReference("User");

Comment: If the app crashes, there is a stack trace. Please look that up on logcat, and add it to your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I should add on Gradle (Project File):

```
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0'
}
```

And Add on Gradle on (Module File):

```
dependencies {
.
.
.
 }
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```